# Returning JSONObject from spring controller gives 406 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My Spring Controller of Spring JSON application returns a JSONObject. On accessing the url, i am getting 406 error page. 
It works when i return String or ArrayList.

Spring Controller:

```
package com.mkyong.common.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Controller
public class JSONController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONObject test() {
        try {
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
            result.put("name", "Dade")
                    .put("age", 23)
                    .put("married", false);
            return result;
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JSONController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

How can i resolve this issue? Thanks for help. I am new to Spring MVC, couldn't found resolution to this issue in the existing SO answers.

Comment: I think you need to indicate the response content-type for the return value of your function
try this:
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")

Let me know if that works to write a better answer

Comment: @JorgeGarita Doesn't work. Same response.

Comment: Spring MVC supports JSON serialization via Jackson, not JSONObject

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Just checked, It works with json-smart-1.1.jar. Is it a part of jackson project?

Comment: put age value as string i.e. "23"

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to manually do something that Spring MVC already it automatically for you. Spring automatically deduces a representation of the returning type and does a converstion. How it does it you can learn from  http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc. In your case its converting to JSON.

> It works when i return String or ArrayList

What happens under the hood is that Spring MVC is using Jackson library, to convert the return type to JSON. And since it has no issue converting the String or List type, all works OK.

What happens in the code you've posted is that, Jackson's object mapper is trying to convert JSONObject instance to JSON, and this fails, cause jackson expects a [POJO](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPlain_Old_Java_Object&ei=__2bVNa7J4rMygOciIHICA&usg=AFQjCNFuTkcMySFYcLEexbCnwFUPp34PZg&sig2=FtmXX6M4eYEPud8mpjU2oQ&bvm=bv.82001339,d.bGQ) object which JSONObject instance isn't.

To have it work you should simply write your POJO and return it. So something like

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Boolean married;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Boolean getMarried() {
        return married;
    }

    public void setMarried(Boolean married) {
        this.married = married;
    }
}
```

and have your method changed to

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public Person test() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Dade");
        person.setAge(23);
        person.setMarried(false);
        return person;
    }
```

For what concerns your error, the same exception you will see in the working example if you for example delete getters and setters, or name them wrongly, an exception happens while trying to convert to a representation and you get a 406 error

Comment: If you go by the same logic, a Map also is not a POJO. How do you square this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set headers in `@RequestMapping` and return `HashMap`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "json", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, String> helloJson() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("k1", "v1");
    map.put("k2", "v2");
    map.put("k3", "v3");
    return map;
}
```