# Return mocked up JSON from file (JSONObject) in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, controller, json

I'd like to mock up some JSON (that I'm reading from a file), and return it as a result of some Spring Controller.

File contains of course correct JSON data format inside, like:

```
{"country":"","city":""...}
```

My controller looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @Value("classpath:/META-INF/json/test.json")
    private Resource testMockup;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject getTest() throws IOException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(FileUtils.readFileToString(testMockup.getFile(), CharEncoding.UTF_8));
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

There is no issue with reading the file itself etc.
`jsonObject` itself, is correct from debbuging PoV, however I'm getting *HTTP Status 406* from the browser.
I've tried also just returning String (by returning `jsonObject.toString()`), instead of `JSONObject`.
However it causes encoding issue - so that JSON from the browser, is not the JSON itself (some additional slashes, quotation marks etc.).

Is there any way, to return JSON from file?

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me.

Java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.*;

@RestController("/beers")
public class BeersController {

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    Object getBeers() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/static/json/beers.json");
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return mapper.readValue(resource.getInputStream(), Object.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Kotlin:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/beers")
class BeersController {

    @GetMapping
    fun getBeers(): Any? {
        val resource = ClassPathResource("/static/json/beers.json")
        return ObjectMapper().readValue(resource.inputStream, Any::class.java)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(
      value = "/test", 
      method = RequestMethod.GET, 
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )

    String getTest() {
        return "json/test.json";
    }
}
```

This worked for me.

Path to JSON file: `\src\main\resources\static\json\test.json`

Answer (score 0):

That't not valid JSON. If it's not a typo, try reformatting your file to look like

```
{"country":"","city":""}
```

Note the opening quote around the property name.

Comment: Sorry, I've just fixed it. It was an issue only here, on my input for this topic, not in code.
JSON looks fine:

{"country":"","city":""}

So root cause of this issue is still unknown.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try replacing the empty strings with values.

Comment: It's not the issue with the JSON itself...
Already tried with:
{"country":"test1","city":"test2"}

Comment: Is this Spring MVC? If so, return a POJO instead of a JSONObject. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642708/returning-jsonobject-from-spring-controller-gives-406-error

Comment: Exactly, but the issue is, that my POJO would be horrible huge, and for now, I just wanted to mocked up something, based on ready JSON file.

Comment: You can return a mock POJO with a single element if you are smoke testing connectivity. When connectivity is confirmed, change the return type to the actual type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with jackson?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object json = mapper.readValue(input, Object.class);
String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(json);
```

And perhaps writing it straight to response body? Jackson should take care of the json.

Answer (score 0):

I know I have been very late for this but why don't you try the below workaround.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getTest() throws IOException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(FileUtils.readFileToString(testMockup.getFile(), CharEncoding.UTF_8));
    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

Comment: You posted the same code, that OP already posted. Where is the answer?

Comment: Changed: @ResponseBody String getTest() and jsonObject.toString();

Comment: Did anyone try this??